# Reledpar and Pagebreaks

Tags: page-breaking, reledmac, reledpar

I am using reledpar to write a document and I can not use a page break command.

Here My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}   
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[nomaxlines]{reledpar}


\usepackage[a4paper,ignoreall,right=2.5cm, left=2.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,top=1.5cm]{geometry}









\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
  \begin{Leftside}

        \beginnumbering
        \pstart


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id tincidunt massa, at fermentum erat. Nunc quis maximus nibh. Aliquam dictum scelerisque nisl, at molestie turpis suscipit et. Vivamus efficitur interdum pulvinar. Phasellus cursus orci eu gravida rhoncus. Praesent aliquam gravida nisl nec tempor. Vestibulum consectetur lectus odio, vel aliquam quam rhoncus in.

Nam lobortis iaculis elit sed placerat. Duis nec molestie metus, quis convallis dui. Suspendisse ultricies efficitur justo, id sollicitudin nunc convallis eu. Pellentesque volutpat turpis vitae est dapibus, vitae mattis nisi interdum. Curabitur sit amet ex ultrices, feugiat est nec, mattis felis. Praesent gravida, leo a venenatis vulputate, diam lorem luctus tortor, at tincidunt lacus sapien quis elit. Maecenas sed ultricies ipsum. Mauris dapibus nunc non eros scelerisque condimentum. Phasellus nec ante eleifend, commodo lectus tristique, fermentum ante. Etiam eget justo dignissim, porttitor felis vitae, efficitur dolor.

Fusce in lectus posuere, dignissim ex quis, accumsan velit. Vivamus faucibus vel lorem a ullamcorper. Sed rhoncus enim et enim volutpat, quis interdum urna hendrerit. Maecenas lorem felis, imperdiet eu sem eget, blandit viverra quam. Donec eget mi nisl. Duis quis euismod mi, id eleifend erat. Ut ac commodo libero, nec cursus velit. Cras nec luctus magna. Integer interdum erat magna, vitae consectetur leo varius quis. Maecenas lacinia eros turpis, a hendrerit velit auctor id. Sed et purus tristique, dictum lectus sit amet, ornare dui.

Ut rutrum eget magna non vehicula. Donec fermentum eros eu urna ultrices feugiat. Quisque dui odio, fermentum id arcu eget, pharetra feugiat leo. Suspendisse at pretium mauris, sit amet luctus massa. Pellentesque varius velit sapien, eget commodo turpis cursus non. Quisque eleifend feugiat dui, id commodo sem convallis id. Morbi lectus tortor, lobortis a ipsum ut, ornare aliquam eros. Cras pellentesque, eros vel egestas tincidunt, est ante vestibulum ex, nec pharetra metus tortor ut felis. Morbi tempus eget mi nec vulputate.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin in enim sagittis, lacinia est id, efficitur massa. Nullam nec turpis et nulla ultrices accumsan. Ut erat massa, semper quis fermentum quis, dapibus quis eros. Aenean vitae augue feugiat, lacinia quam quis, posuere risus. Cras mollis turpis vel velit pulvinar porttitor. In eget rutrum augue. Integer et faucibus lacus. Etiam aliquet dapibus magna pharetra pellentesque. Fusce id arcu in lacus commodo ullamcorper sit amet sed metus. Nunc laoreet erat metus, et euismod diam sagittis non. Maecenas quis laoreet quam. Nullam quis vehicula magna. Donec accumsan nibh egestas nibh ultrices luctus. Fusce quis imperdiet dui, dictum bibendum odio. Phasellus in imperdiet magna.         
        \pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}

              \beginnumbering
\pstart

1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

\ledpb

4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

7 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}    
\end{pages}
\Pages


\end{document}
```

The output simple breaks the page between 1 and 2 item, not after 3, as I expectaded when I placed the command `\ledpb`.

Here the images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the empty line after the first `\pstart`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}   
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[nomaxlines]{reledpar}


\usepackage[a4paper,ignoreall,right=2.5cm, left=2.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,top=1.5cm]{geometry}









\begin{document}

\begin{pages}
  \begin{Leftside}

        \beginnumbering
        \pstart


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed id tincidunt massa, at fermentum erat. Nunc quis maximus nibh. Aliquam dictum scelerisque nisl, at molestie turpis suscipit et. Vivamus efficitur interdum pulvinar. Phasellus cursus orci eu gravida rhoncus. Praesent aliquam gravida nisl nec tempor. Vestibulum consectetur lectus odio, vel aliquam quam rhoncus in.

Nam lobortis iaculis elit sed placerat. Duis nec molestie metus, quis convallis dui. Suspendisse ultricies efficitur justo, id sollicitudin nunc convallis eu. Pellentesque volutpat turpis vitae est dapibus, vitae mattis nisi interdum. Curabitur sit amet ex ultrices, feugiat est nec, mattis felis. Praesent gravida, leo a venenatis vulputate, diam lorem luctus tortor, at tincidunt lacus sapien quis elit. Maecenas sed ultricies ipsum. Mauris dapibus nunc non eros scelerisque condimentum. Phasellus nec ante eleifend, commodo lectus tristique, fermentum ante. Etiam eget justo dignissim, porttitor felis vitae, efficitur dolor.

Fusce in lectus posuere, dignissim ex quis, accumsan velit. Vivamus faucibus vel lorem a ullamcorper. Sed rhoncus enim et enim volutpat, quis interdum urna hendrerit. Maecenas lorem felis, imperdiet eu sem eget, blandit viverra quam. Donec eget mi nisl. Duis quis euismod mi, id eleifend erat. Ut ac commodo libero, nec cursus velit. Cras nec luctus magna. Integer interdum erat magna, vitae consectetur leo varius quis. Maecenas lacinia eros turpis, a hendrerit velit auctor id. Sed et purus tristique, dictum lectus sit amet, ornare dui.

Ut rutrum eget magna non vehicula. Donec fermentum eros eu urna ultrices feugiat. Quisque dui odio, fermentum id arcu eget, pharetra feugiat leo. Suspendisse at pretium mauris, sit amet luctus massa. Pellentesque varius velit sapien, eget commodo turpis cursus non. Quisque eleifend feugiat dui, id commodo sem convallis id. Morbi lectus tortor, lobortis a ipsum ut, ornare aliquam eros. Cras pellentesque, eros vel egestas tincidunt, est ante vestibulum ex, nec pharetra metus tortor ut felis. Morbi tempus eget mi nec vulputate.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin in enim sagittis, lacinia est id, efficitur massa. Nullam nec turpis et nulla ultrices accumsan. Ut erat massa, semper quis fermentum quis, dapibus quis eros. Aenean vitae augue feugiat, lacinia quam quis, posuere risus. Cras mollis turpis vel velit pulvinar porttitor. In eget rutrum augue. Integer et faucibus lacus. Etiam aliquet dapibus magna pharetra pellentesque. Fusce id arcu in lacus commodo ullamcorper sit amet sed metus. Nunc laoreet erat metus, et euismod diam sagittis non. Maecenas quis laoreet quam. Nullam quis vehicula magna. Donec accumsan nibh egestas nibh ultrices luctus. Fusce quis imperdiet dui, dictum bibendum odio. Phasellus in imperdiet magna.         
        \pend
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}

              \beginnumbering
\pstart
1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
\ledpb

4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

7 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}    
\end{pages}
\Pages


\end{document}
```

In general, you should not create paragraph inside \pstart, but prefer have one § by `\pstart...\pend`